# How to extend existing template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am working with legacy code of a template that is based on

```
  template<class keyType, class dType> Foo Bar(const dType val)
```

Somewhere in that code is a place where someone made a debug function like this:

```
virtual void getDebugStr01(int db_id, OFCString & db_str)
{
    //OFCStringStream ss;
    if(db_id==0)
    {
        map<keyType, dType>::iterator it = m_stateData.begin();
        for(;it!=m_stateData.end();it++)
        {
            (it->second).getDebugStr01(db_str);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would need to use the template class with a float. Is there anyway to do this?

Currently I get a:

```
   error C2228: left of '.getDebugStr01' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can't you just overload the method to take a float as parameter? Or make it a function template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDebugStr01()` should be a member of a `class/struct`. `virtual` methods cannot be stand alone.

You can do something like,

```
Foo Bar (const float f)
{
...
}
```